# Right justify text in bottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I have text under the bottomSheet. I want to justify this text to the right. The code I use is below. The result was not what I wanted

```
bottomSheet:
           Text("Siya Teknoloji Yazilim İnavasyon LTD.ŞTİ",
           textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
```

The visual view is as follows.

[image]

Comment: You can wrap it with ```Align``` widget and use ```Alignment.start```

Comment: Unfortunately the whole page is scrolling

Comment: can you include an image what are you  trying to get

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap with container.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 48 + 12 * 2),/// fab size+padding
  child: Text(
    "Siya Teknoloji Yazilim İnavasyon LTD.ŞTİ",
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
),
```

More about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).